# Is PGP symmetric encryption as effective as Apple Keychain?

Tags: passwords, gnupg, keychain

I used to use Apple's Keychain to store passwords, but I got tired of trying to figure out how to transfer them when I changed computers, so I switched to using a text file encrypted with gpg symmetric encryption:

```
$ gpg --symmetric my_passwords.txt
```

**Is this any less secure than the Keychain app?**

The file has 0600 permissions, and it seems like even if I was using gpg w/ a public/private key, if someone got access to the `my_passwords.txt` file they'd have access to my private key anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, PGP encryption has never been broken.

So my answer would be: PGP is as least as pretty good as Apple's Keychain.

Comment: ha! funny pun :)

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IncrediblyLamePun? :-)

Comment: @Johannes Rössel: Sorry - will try to improve in the future.

Comment: Tropes aren't bad ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The default symmetric cipher used by [gpg](http://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual.html#AEN185) is [CAST5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAST5) while Mac OS X encryption tools ([File Vault](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/Security_Overview/Security_Services/Security_Services.html)) use 128-bit [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) cipher.

Both ciphers are considered secure against "cryptographic breaks" so **their security for encription is related only to the security of the password**.